# Magento2 : How to show New label in product list page

Tags: magento2, new-products

I want need to show New label on new product in product list page.

Help me for the achieve this task.

How can it will Show in magento2 ?

Comment: You mean if we set product new fields in admin, this label will show?

Comment: I need to show New as label in product list page, product set as new from admin by product set as new from to date.

Comment: Is it working with my answer? :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create helper and add code.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface;

class Newlabel extends \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data
{

    /**
     * @var TimezoneInterface
     */
    protected $localeDate;

    public function __construct(
        TimezoneInterface $localeDate
    ) {
        $this->localeDate = $localeDate;
    }

    public function isProductNew($product)
    {
        $newsFromDate = $product->getNewsFromDate();
        $newsToDate = $product->getNewsToDate();
        if (!$newsFromDate && !$newsToDate) {
            return false;
        }

        return $this->localeDate->isScopeDateInInterval(
            $product->getStore(),
            $newsFromDate,
            $newsToDate
        );
    }
}
```

Add below code to **list.phtml** file (**in foreach**)

```
<?php $helper = $this->helper('Vendor\Module\Helper\Newlabel'); ?>
<?php if($helper->isProductNew($_product)): ?>
<div class="new-lable">
    <?php echo __('New'); ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And finally it will show **NEW** label in product list page. Working Great.

Comment: hi @suresh how do we show hot and sale labels ?

Comment: What about the full page cache? As the product list might be cached, you have to ensure it is purged when the product is now longer new.

Comment: Thanks for nice code!!!

Answer (score 12):

Propably the best option is to add new helper with following code:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product as ModelProduct;
use Magento\Store\Model\Store;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface;

class HelperName extends \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data
{

    /**
     * @var TimezoneInterface
     */
    protected $localeDate;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        TimezoneInterface $localeDate
    ) {
        $this->localeDate = $localeDate;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function isProductNew(ModelProduct $product)
    {
        $newsFromDate = $product->getNewsFromDate();
        $newsToDate = $product->getNewsToDate();
        if (!$newsFromDate && !$newsToDate) {
            return false;
        }

        return $this->localeDate->isScopeDateInInterval(
            $product->getStore(),
            $newsFromDate,
            $newsToDate
        );
    }
}
```

Then in .phtml file use this:

```
$helper = $this->helper('Vendor\Module\Helper\HelperName');
```

and in products `foreach`:

```
<?php if($helper->isProductNew($_product)): ?>
    Your label code here
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Any reason to use `\Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data` instead of `\Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper`?

Comment: hi @ideo how do we show 'hot' and 'sale' labels for the product in the category list page do u have any idea?

Comment: What about the full page cache? As the product list might be cached, you have to ensure it is purged when the product is now longer new.