# Cache aware display of "product is new" badge

Tags: magento2.2.6, full-page-cache

This is a follow up of

[Magento2 : How to show New label in product list page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113759/magento2-how-to-show-new-label-in-product-list-page)

If I understand the proposed solution correctly, the product will still be shown as new as long as the full page cache does not expire.

What is an elegant solution for this?

I have something like the following in mind:

- Detect somehow if product is no longer new (for example a cron that runs once a day, detect if the current day is just product-is-new-until plus one) or cache the latest state of product-is-new
- If the product is now longer new, clear the product related cache tag.

Would that work? Did anybody do something like this, yet?

Comment: Normally if you are using FPC you need to clear FPC once in a day , then need to run Crawling script for early access. using sitemap.xml file

Comment: I would not like to clear the FPC ---> would appreciate if it can stay for a longer time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

step 1: create a cronjob which needs to run once in a day

step 2: get collection of products expired yesterday (something like this  "NewsToDate" == date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 day")) )

step 3 : iterate  collection and invalidate product cache

```
$product->cleanCache();
$this->_eventManager->dispatch('clean_cache_by_tags', ['object' => $product]);
```

Comment: Drawback: If the cron job did not run every day, the process breaks

Comment: Just have a look if `time()` is after `news_to_date` if true it's not new anymore