# Magento 2 - check if product is new

Tags: magento2, product, catalog

How can I check if a product is new in Magento 2?

I found this solution for Magento 1:

```
function isProductNew(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product)
{
    $newsFromDate = $product->getNewsFromDate();
    $newsToDate   = $product->getNewsToDate();
    if (!$newsFromDate && !$newsToDate) {
        return false;
    }
    return Mage::app()->getLocale()
            ->isStoreDateInInterval($product->getStoreId(), $newsFromDate, $newsToDate);
}
```

How can I migrate this code to make it work in Magento 2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Propably the best option is to add new helper with following code:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product as ModelProduct;
use Magento\Store\Model\Store;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface;

class HelperName extends \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data
{

    /**
     * @var TimezoneInterface
     */
    protected $localeDate;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        TimezoneInterface $localeDate
    ) {
        $this->localeDate = $localeDate;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function isProductNew(ModelProduct $product)
    {
        $newsFromDate = $product->getNewsFromDate();
        $newsToDate = $product->getNewsToDate();
        if (!$newsFromDate && !$newsToDate) {
            return false;
        }

        return $this->localeDate->isScopeDateInInterval(
            $product->getStore(),
            $newsFromDate,
            $newsToDate
        );
    }
}
```

Then in .phtml file use this:

```
$helper = $this->helper('Vendor\Module\Helper\HelperName');
```

and in products `foreach`:

```
<?php if($helper->isProductNew($_product)): ?>
    Your label code here
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I get `Undefined property: Company\Base\Helper\Product::$localeDate`. Can you also post the missing code for `$localeDate` please?

Comment: check this link :- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113759/magento2-how-to-show-new-label-in-product-list-page